# Chosen Search Box with JQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script for choose selected in drop down use bootstrap based on reference in google: https://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/

But my script not working. Please advice if I wrong.. Thanks

Follow My Script:

```js
<script src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/development/SiteAssets/Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script>

// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function ()  
{
    $(SPUtility.GetSPField('Owner Name').Controls).find('select').chosen({width: "350px"});

    console.log("test");
    
    var cascadeArray = new Array();
        
        //filter
        cascadeArray.push({
            parentFormField: "Owner", //Display name on form of field from parent list
            childList: "Vessel", //List name of child list
            childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
            childFormField: "Vessel Name", //Display name on form of the child field
            parentFieldInChildList: "Owner Name", //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
            //firstOptionText: "< Select a Claim Activity Type >"
        });
        $().HillbillyCascade(cascadeArray);
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: please put your code here.

Comment: You could have posted your code here to get proper help. **that would have taken less time** then the actual screenshot and blurring out the `url's` . Please consider adding the actual `code`

Comment: @MajiD please check my posting

Comment: whats is the result of this "SPUtility.GetSPField('Owner Name').Controls" ?

Comment: @MajiD it was supposed to show the search results in the drop down, but it didn't work for me. Is there something wrong? Because previously I used this code a running, but when I migrated it didn't work